# Trim text using Jquery with clickable "More" but keep text format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want t use the below Jquery to truncate the text in the div ID="content" below, but I want to keep the text format too, as when I use the jquery I lose`<br>` im the text which works as paragraph separator.

How can I fix that?

```js
var minimized_elements = $('#content'); 

minimized_elements.each(function() {
  var t = $(this).text();
  if (t.length < 300) return;

  $(this).html(
    t.slice(0, 300) + '<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">More</a>' +
    '<span style="display:none;">' + t.slice(300, t.length) + ' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a></span>'
  );

});

$('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide().prev().hide();
  $(this).next().show();
});

$('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
 It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content content
    here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text
  
  <br>
  <br>
 It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text

</div>
```

Comment: Your using text() which strips any markup, if you wanted the markup you could use html() instead. You would then have to ensure that each HTML tag is closed correctly. Does this have to be character count? could it be by height/width then you could easily fix this with a little Css

Comment: @MugiwaraUK  Thank you it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gerrit_Luimstra, Thank you for your help you have answered my first question

@MugiwaraUK, Thank you for answering my second question, your solution worked!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so what is happening is that you only use the text inside of the element. But, you are saying you want to also use the element to add the sliced text to later.

A simple fix for this (if you know what type of element it is, such as a paragraph element) is:

```
   $(this).html(
    '<p>'+ t.slice(0, 300) + '</p>' + '<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">More</a>' +
    '<span style="display:none;">' + t.slice(300, t.length) + ' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a></span>'
  );
```

Is this what you are looking for?

**Edited code:**

The HTML:

```
<div id="element">
  <p>Lorum ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Hello this is an example text..</p>
</div>

<p>What this does, is it iterates through each paragraph element. 
   It cuts it at 10 letters, but then a word can be slices in two, 
   which is not good. 
   So the script will continue to remove the last pieces of this cut word until it finds a space.</p>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$("#element p").each(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  var sliced = jQuery.trim(text).substring(0, 10);

  // inverse loop through the string to remove the charachters of the broken word...
  for (var i = sliced.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(sliced[i] == " "){
      // if a space occurs, break the loop, but remove this space:
      sliced = sliced.slice(0, -1);
      break;
    } else {
      // if the charachter is not a space, remove the charachter.
      sliced = sliced.slice(0, -1);
    }
  }

  // optional
  sliced += " ... read more";

  // output the text. 
  document.write("Outputs: " + sliced + "<br>");

  // OR you can change the paragraphs text directly like this:
  // $(this).text(sliced);
});
```

Comment: Thnak you Gerrit, but still the code is not performing as I want.

Comment: Can you explain a little further what it is you wish to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you Gerrit, but still the code is not performing as I want. I have text with multiple paragraphs, this script combines all paragraphs into one, I do not want that, I want it to truncate the text while keeping the space between the paragraphs also it truncates the words, such as assassinate will make it 'ass...More', I do not want that, I want it to truncate the space between words.

Comment: @Dani is this what you are after? http://codepen.io/gerritman123/pen/QEqVEr

Comment: Gerrit, Thank you for taking the time to write a new code. But you do not have to, that code I have on the initial post is working but it needs to be fixed. the text that I want to slice has <br> </br> in it and it seems the code that I have on my initial question ignores deletes those <br> and I end up with a full text in one paragraph. plus it truncated words, it suppose to see if the minimized texted character is in a word, it should go to the closest space and truncate.

Comment: @Dani I want to help you, but I can't understand what you are trying to accomplish. I am going to upvote this, so others can help you.

Comment: @Gerrit_Luimstra I have updated my question, my issue is the <br> disappear from the output text, I want to reserve the <br> please help.